# SQL outer join vs Neo4J Cipher

Tags: sql, encryption, neo4j, cypher, translate

I am new in Neo4J Cipher, I know what I want to get in SQL, but can't create query in Cipher.

Let's have 3 tables:

```
Pers(persId,name,workId,born)
Work(workId,name)
Friend(pers1Id,pers2Id)
```

Problem:
find people, who work in the same company and are not friends and age difference is less than5.
In SQL a simple query looks like below:

```
select * from Pers p1 join Pers p2 on p1.workId=p2.workId 
where not exists
(select 1 from Friend f where p1.persId in (f.person1Id,f.person2Id) 
and p2.persId in (f.person1Id,f.person2Id) ) 
and abs(p1.born-p2.born)<5
```

what about Neo4J Cipher?
Any help will be appreciate, especially how to translate SQL to Cipher queries.
Mirek

Comment: It helps to include what you've tried so far, even if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have :Person and :Workplace labels. Let's assume these kinds of relationships already exist:

```
(:Person)-[:WorksAt]->(:Workplace)
(:Person)-[:FriendsWith]->(:Person)
```

Your Cypher query would look something like:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:WorksAt]->()<-[:WorksAt]-(p2:Person)
WHERE NOT (p1)-[:FriendsWith]-(p2)
AND abs(p1.born-p2.born) < 5
RETURN p1, p2
```

Though keep in mind I think you will get two rows per pairing, with the order switched (we can eliminate that without much trouble if you need to).

In general, it's a good idea to draw out a diagram of the pattern or query, and from there it's usually not too hard to translate that to Cypher.

Answer (score 0):

As InverseFalcon's answer shows, you can use the `WHERE NOT <pattern>` construct to express an antijoin (sometimes called left anti-semijoin) operation.

I just finished an academic paper on the subject - the paper is currently under peer review, but it can help you understand the connection between relational algebra and Cypher: http://docs.inf.mit.bme.hu/ingraph/pub/btw2017-opencypher.pdf